# returning rows based on some criteria and if no row match the criteria then return all rows in mariadb sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to fetch rows based on some criteria here. What I want is to get the rows if the rows available with matching criteria AND if does not match then return all rows.

Below is my query.

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
        CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%10%' > 0) 
        // Line 3       
        THEN
           (SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%10%' LIMIT 0,10)t
        ELSE 
           (SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 0,10)t   
        END
```

I am getting syntax error at line 3

Comment: Efficient solution would be to do it in two queries and handle it in your application code (eg: PHP). First query would get the matching results; if there are not any results (which *will not be* the case at most of the times), then and only run the second query to get all results.

Comment: What if there are 7 users matching '%10%', do you want those 7 only, or should 3 other fill up to 10?

Comment: @jarlh It seems that when at least a match of  *'%10%'*  is present show those records limits upto 10 or else just show data with limit 10. So if the able has less than 10 records then it will show only those existing data.

Comment: @James, yeah, that's what he is trying to do. But maybe he rather wants a combined result?

Comment: @jarlh if there are 7 users matching '%10% then only 7 users would be there.

Comment: @James no combine result. if users are matching '%10%' then , fetch those rows otherwise 'Select * from users' is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT u.*
 FROM users u
 WHERE u.user_name LIKE '%10%'
 LIMIT 0, 10
) UNION ALL
(SELECT u.*
 FROM users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_name LIKE '%10%')
 LIMIT 0, 10
) ;
```

You can also just use `OR`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_name LIKE '%10%' OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_name LIKE '%10%')
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mariadb `if-then-else` statement

```
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%10%') > 0
      SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%10%' LIMIT 0,10
   ELSE
      SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name
   END IF;
```